# eclipse content assist inserts at wrong position

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

in my xhtml-files I have some code like:

```
 <p:tab title="title">  
    <div>foo</div>
```

when the cursor now is placed at the end of line after "/div" and than I call the content assist, to complete the p:tab.
After I enter the selection in the assistan, it places the "/p:tab" after the start-tab in the line of "p:tab", but I want the content assist to place the ending tag at the new line after div or where the cursor stands.
Has someone an idea, how I can configure the assist to do this or is this a bug in eclipse (4.23.0)
thanks in advice

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was indeed a bug in the previous Eclipse version, which is fixed in the current Eclipse version. So better keep your software up-to-date to avoid such issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I updated to 2022-06 (4.24.0), but no change....

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: HTML Editor. I testet it with photon, and there it works right.

Comment: Which HTML Editor? Please show a screenshot.

Comment: Please show a screenshot.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the *editor*.